# Is there anything in the NEC that would prevent me from attaching MC cable with ground to EMT with a compression coupling?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Is there anything in the NEC that would prevent me from attaching MC cable with ground to EMT with a compression coupling?  I will be skinning the MC cable roughly about 10 to 15 feet where it enters a 1900 box to feed an outlet.

Edit:  the compression coupling would not be accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I could think of that might be wrong with that is the wires in the MC may not be listed / marked as THHN or THWN, even though that's what it is.

Could you use greenfield (FMC) and pull in your wire?

Regarding the coupling - I think you'll have to use a MC/AC box connector and EMT box connector joined together by a female-female threaded coupler.

edit:  Actually it looks like there are EMT to FMC couplers:

http://www.bptfittings.com/Home/ProductDetail?s=582-DC(Catalog%20Num)

[image: EMT to FMC coupler]

Comment: I also wonder if the compression fitting is listed to be used with MC cable *and* EMT...

Comment: Whoa, hold on!  I think you'll have to use a barrel - female to female threaded coupler - between an MC box connector and EMT box connector.  An EMT connector will NOT work properly nor be listed for use with flex / MC / AC.

Comment: Alright, I think I'll use flex with a male threaded connector with THHN and a 1/2" female threaded EMT connector. Skipping the MC and compression coupling all together.

Comment: Interesting. I am wondering where you found a female threaded EMT connector. We just use a rigid coupling to join two different raceways. They make adapters for just this occasion though.

Comment: @ArchonOSX Haha, you're right I need to use a rigid threaded female coupling